# How to write a policy to validate HMAC-SHA256 token passed in authorization header of rest api?

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-authentication, azure-policy

I am currently using apim for authorizing my tokens by passing to a third party . below is my policy.xml

```
<policies>

    <inbound>

        <base />

        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Authorization Failed. Check Bearer Token">

            <openid-config url="https://keycloak.ff.acom/realms/ff/.well-known/openid-configuration" />

        </validate-jwt>

    </inbound>

    <backend>

        <base />

    </backend>

    <outbound>

        <base />

    </outbound>

    <on-error>

        <base />

    </on-error>

</policies>
```

I have a new requirement where the token will be hmac-sha256.which will be generated using a clientid and client secret. How do I validate the same in apim? Kindly guide

Answer (score 0):

I have taken references from the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-jwt-policy#token-validation-with-rsa-certificate) and referred this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#configure-a-jwt-validation-policy-to-pre-authorize-requests) as well.

If you are using Azure AD for `openid-config` , you can use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{aad-tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration` for v1 endpoint and `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{aad-tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` for v2 endpoint. Here `aad-tenant` is your Azure AD `tenant-id`.

I have added the bearer token generated using the client id and client secret in the request header and given the below inbound policy in apim for jwt token validation and it worked for me.

[image]

[image]

[image]